# Hyperlinks from font awesome icons not working when clicked, only when right clicked

Tags: fonts, hyperlink, tabs, font-awesome

I have 4 Font Awesome social media icons at the top of my home page (http://southeastmed.org) with hyperlinks to FB, LinkedIn, Google+ and YouTube. But clicking them does nothing. Right clicking and opening in a new tab does work. How do I get these icons to link correctly? By the way, there is also a rotation animation on the Font Awesome icons during hover. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling javascript on that page fixes the links. So I think you have something overriding the click event on those buttons and breaking the click event.

Answer (score 0):

hi please use **target="_blank"** in Hyperlinks Tag........

Otherwise just remove a p Tag and use div  Tag for social media container(p tag)